# Path Structure for Processing inputs to step function "AppManaged" and not app managed for a sagemaker Job

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I have a use case where i am running a sagemaker processing job  in a step function , now for this use case input is :

```
"ProcessingInputs": [
                  {
                    "InputName": "input1",
                    "S3Input": {
                      "S3Uri": "s3://<s3-bucket>/ecom/sagemaker/processing/scripts/ecommerce_activation/Refactored_Python/pullProcessCustHier.py",
                      "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/input/code",
                      "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                      "S3InputMode": "File",
                      "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "InputName": "input2",
                    "S3Input": {
                      "S3Uri": "s3://<s3bucket>/ecom/sagemaker/processing/scripts/ecommerce_activation/sql/Customer_Hierarchy.sql",
                      "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/sql",
                      "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                      "S3InputMode": "File",
                      "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated"
                    }
                  }
                ],
```

In   "ContainerEntrypoint" i need to run lets say pull_cust_data.py file . which runs fine as per input 1 .

```
 "ContainerEntrypoint": [
                    "python3",
                    "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/pull_cust_data.py"
                  ]
```

In input 2 i am loading a sql file , which contains a get query to a table.

now in python code its looking for

```
  # Read in the query
    with open('./sql/Customer_Hierarchy.sql', 'r') as f_in:
        query = f_in.read()
```

This is where i get a error as FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './sql/Customer_Hierarchy.sql'

What would be the right way , since i dont want to update the path in python file.